# SQL output related query .merging five values in a column into a single value separated by comma

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

My input is in the below form:

```
select a.ab from tableone a ;
```

Result :

```
aa
bb
cc
```

****Desired output:****

```
('aa','bb','cc')
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS that are you using along with its version.

Comment: "PL/SQL" (although wrongly tagged) means "Oracle", @Arun.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` function.

Table contents:

```
SQL> select ab from tableone;

AB
--
aa
bb
cc
```

Result you need:

```
SQL> select '(' || listagg(chr(39) || ab || chr(39), ',') within group (order by ab) || ')' result from tableone;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
('aa','bb','cc')

SQL>
```

Comment: @SudharsanRavichandran, Please accept this answer (_by clicking the tick mark_) if it resolved your problem. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)